# dynamically create TD using jquery and print all data

Tags: jquery, for-loop

With a limit of 3 TR. Dynamically create a number of TD divided by the number of data. And I want to print all data in TD. So, for example have 12 elements then 3 TR's will get generated and 4 TD. My problem is I cannot print all the data. How can I get to print all data?

NOTE : DATA IS NOT FIXED. IT IS DYNAMIC ALSO. IT CAN BE OTHER NUMBERS

Thanks in advance.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
            var data = 12;
            var maxRow = 3
            var maxCol = (12 / 3) +1;
            var table = $("#table tbody");
            var ctr = 0;
            var a = 0;
            for (var row = 0; row < maxRow; row++) {
                table.append('<tr></tr>');
                var appendRow = $('#table tr:last');
                a = a + 1;
                for (var i = a; i < data; i++) {
                    if (i == 0 || i % maxCol != 0) {
                        appendRow.append('<td>' + i + '</td>');
                        //ctr++;
                    }
                    if (i == maxCol)
                    {
                        a = i;
                        break;
                    }
                }
            }

        });
```

Expected Result

```html
<table id='table'>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>1</td>
      <td>2</td>
      <td>3</td>
      <td>4</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>5</td>
      <td>6</td>
      <td>7</td>
      <td>8</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>9</td>
      <td>10</td>
      <td>11</td>
      <td>12</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Instead of getting that I get this. 
[my result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/njBas.png)

Answer (score 0):

There are some problems in your code.

First of all. maxCol will be (Data/rows) i.e. 12/3 = 4.

```
var maxCol = Math.ceil(12 / 3); // To get the columns to fit the data.
```

`i` will go equal to `data`

```
for (var i = a; i <= data; i++)
```

The break condition needs to be updated. Also, append a `td` when breaking otherwise it will skip some values.

```
 if (i%maxCol == 0)
 {
       appendRow.append('<td>' + i + '</td>');
       a = i;
       break;
 }
```

The `i == 0` condition is redundant because `i` will never be zero according to tour code.

```
if (i == 0 || i % maxCol != 0)
```

[JS Fiddle link](https://jsfiddle.net/rx4mupz3/)

Comment: Hmm this seems right when the data is divisible by 3. But what if the total number of data is not divisible by 3? I think it will not print all the numbers.

Comment: @megatron You will have to modify the code according your needs. You can fit any amount of data in any table. Just some cells will be empty if the size of data is not right.